# Why is Python not finding a file in a directory?

Tags: python, command-prompt

Python code is saying it can't find a file that is clearly in the directory when running code from the command prompt. It randomly alternates between finding the file vs. error when I run the code.

See error result from command prompt below - the beginning of the code is an os.listdir command to list the files in the directory (it includes the file, paths_3.csv).

```
In [15]: %run neilsen_spread.py
['1000', '30000', '5000', '5000 no drift', 'paths_3.csv', 'test_run']
1 out of 17
2022-02-24 15:37:23.868833
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
~\neilsen_spread.py in <module>
    192
    193 ######## Set parameters ##############################
--> 194 opt_val('chains.csv', .0195)
    195
    196 #print ("My program took", time.time() - start_time, "to run")

~\neilsen_spread.py in opt_val(chains_csv, risk_free)
     78         # get data file
     79         retn_file = r'C:\Users\joshd\swanpaths\paths_' + str(ret_tm) + '.csv'
---> 80         data = pd.read_csv(retn_file)
     81         len_drifts = len(data['total_retn'])
     82         log_return = np.log(data['total_retn'])

C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision)
    674         )
    675
--> 676         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    677
    678     parser_f.__name__ = name

C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    446
    447     # Create the parser.
--> 448     parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)
    449
    450     if chunksize or iterator:

C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    878             self.options["has_index_names"] = kwds["has_index_names"]
    879
--> 880         self._make_engine(self.engine)
    881
    882     def close(self):

C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _make_engine(self, engine)
   1112     def _make_engine(self, engine="c"):
   1113         if engine == "c":
-> 1114             self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
   1115         else:
   1116             if engine == "python":

C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in __init__(self, src, **kwds)
   1889         kwds["usecols"] = self.usecols
   1890
-> 1891         self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
   1892         self.unnamed_cols = self._reader.unnamed_cols
   1893

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source()

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File C:\Users\joshd\swanpaths\paths_3.0.csv does not exist: 'C:\\Users\\joshd\\swanpaths\\paths_3.0.csv'
```

Comment: [mcve], please. It's not clear at all just from what you've shown that the file exists.

Comment: Yes, there's a `paths_3.csv` in the directory.  But if you were to ACTUALLY READ THE ERROR MESSAGE, it's complaining about the lack of `paths_3.0.csv`.  Apparently the `ret_tm` value you're using to generate the filename is a float, rather than an integer.

Comment: I would be able to help you better with two more pieces of information: proof that the CSV file exists, and minimal code as chepner advised.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution that you can use, is to verify that you really have the file, where you believe it is.

Just as a confirmation, you can also share the result with us as has been suggested.

To verify or check all the files in the directory, do the following:

```
import os
my_dir_path = 'C:\Users\joshd\swanpaths\paths_'

dir_content = os.listdir(my_dir_path)

print(dir_content)
```

Kindly share the output of the **print(dir_content)** here, so we confirm  that the file is in the directory.